# Setting value of cells in table based on popup

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, row

I have a table of data and a button at in the last column called "update".

Update opens a model pop-up, populates it with the contents of the row where the button lives and allows input.

I want to put the new values entered in the pop-up back into the row.

A piece of my Table looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered tablesorter" id="mainTable">
<thead><tr><th>Reset</th><th>Relationship</th><th>Family</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone#</th><th>Status&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Arrived?</th><th>Update</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td><div><button class="btn btn-primary myButton" disabled="disabled" id="resetButton" data-id="Samuel Rahimi">Reset</button></div></td><td id=relationship>Friend</td><td id=personName>Samuel Rahimi</td><td id=fname>Samuel</td><td id=lname>Rahimi</td><td id=email>unknown@gmail.com</td><td id=phone>1-212-555-1212</td><td id=Status> </td>
<td><div><button class="btn btn-primary myButton" id="updateButton" data-fname="Samuel" data-lname="Rahimi" data-email="unknown@gmail.com" data-phone="1-212-555-1212" data-note="" data-id="Samuel Rahimi">Update</button></div></td></tr>
```

Here is the jquery script to set the values in the modal:

```
  <script>
$(function() 
{
$('button#updateButton').on('click', function (e) {
    var getIdFromRow = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(getIdFromRow)
    var x = $(this).data('fname')
    console.log(x)
    $('#newAttendeeFname').val($(this).data('fname'))
    $('#newAttendeeLname').val($(this).data('lname'))
    $('#newAttendeeEmail').val($(this).data('email'))
    $('#newAttendeePhone').val($(this).data('phone'))
    $('#newAttendeeNote').val($(this).data('note'))         
    $('#addAttendeeModal').modal('show')
    }
)
}


)
</script>
```

And here is my attempt at getting the content of the modal back in to the table row:

```
<script>
//
// This is the function that is called when the button for a new attendee is clicked
//
$(function() 
    {
        $('button#addAttendeeSubmit').on('click', function (e) {

            fname = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeFname").value
            lname = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeLname").value
            email = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeEmail").value
            note  = document.getElementById ("newAttendeeNote").value
            phone = document.getElementById ("newAttendeePhone").value

            newInfo = 'fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&email='+email+'&phone='+phone+'&note='+note+'&action=updateAttendee'
            // for testing we can alert the variables 
            //alert(newInfo)
            console.log(newInfo)
                    // just put HELLO in there for now
            $(this).find("td#relationship").html('HELLO')


            // Call the php function to update the database
            $.ajax({type: "GET", url:"EventCheckInFunctions.php", data: newInfo})
            // refresh the page - good time to pick up any changes from DB
            //location.reload(true);
            // Really remove the modal so that values will all be reinitialized
            //$('#addAttendeeModal').remove();
            })
    }
)
</script>
```

I have tried various find, closest etc ...

Any thoughts (and sorry for the table looking like such a mess, I did a view source to get it as it is actually generated with php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want "$(this).find", since it doesn't reference the table and it's td's.
Try something like:

```
 $("#mainTable td#relationship").html('HELLO');
```

---

To find the specific row the button is on, you can use something like:

```
 $(this).closest('tr').find("td#relationship").html('HELLO');
```

Or, you can use jQuery.data to store the child index.

Comment: Nice ... but how do I reference "this" row ... ie the row in which the button was pressed ? I thought i could do a closest or some variation on that ?

Comment: I edited  my answer to include this… if you can add a unique row id?  If not, I think jQuery.data is the best approach

Comment: right - i kindof figured that is what I should do. I was being "lazy", not wanting to add the row_number to the id on each row (which of course if the right thing to do).

Comment: sorry, that was too convoluted.  Edited again-- of course you only need to find the closest `tr`.  You should still consider making your `id`s unique.